# IOS Cordova Lock SplashScreen Orientation

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, orientation

### Background

I'm using Cordova to deploy javascript to iOS devices.  Along with this, I'm using the CDVSplashScreen plugin in order to show my own splashscreen.

### What I need help with

I want to be able to lock *only* the Launch/Splash Screens and then allow the app to reorient as it will for all other views.

### What I've tried

I've added the following to my **config.xml** file:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000000" />
```

And I added the following code to both the **CDVSplashScreen.m** and **CDVViewController+SplashScreen.m** files:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

### The Results:

What I've added to the *config.xml* file appears to have locked the **Launch Screen** in portrait mode...however, after the *SplashScreen* appears, the view will rotate freely to landscape mode.

I don't believe that the *supportedInterfaceOrientations* function is doing anything at all where it's at - it only works in the mainViewController (but then the entire app is stuck in Portrait mode).

### My Plea

Has anyone used this unique conglomeration of plugins before with the same requirement of a locked SplashScreen before?  How did you solve it?

Comment: Have you tried this plugin? https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your suggestions.  I ended up setting the orientation in the following function in the **MainViewController:**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
      self.acceptedOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
  return self;
}
```

This seemed to lock the SplashScreen in portrait mode for me.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked, but you could try the following:

1. Lock the orientation in Xcode to your needs. (Xcode -> General -> Deployment info)
2. Put an event handler in your javascript:

```js
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  // Do some DOM-/CSS-manipulation depending on the value in window.orientation
}, false);
```

3. Or you could use CSS to make changes:

```css
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  /* rotate your container */
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* rotate your container */
}
```

But I'm not sure that the device is firing the event.